# ASP.net Wizard Control Steps on top

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been trying to find a decent solution to using the wizard control but I can't seem to find a simple solution that allows me to put the wizard steps on top of the control instead of to the left. 
Eventually I have to have some images too instead of only text.

I'm thinking about using a multiview to make my own wizard, just to have complete freedom...

any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control this by changing / using CSS for those items in the .aspx for the wizard.

Here's a tutorial for this:

http://weblogs.asp.net/grantbarrington/archive/2009/08/11/styling-the-asp-net-wizard-control-to-have-the-steps-across-the-top.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses the custom user control http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CustomizingWizardNav.aspx